# CSS Style not being picked up when deployed in netlify

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, netlify

I have created a create-react-app and trying to deploy it using Netlify for the first time (sample is [here](https://cocky-fermat-241cbc.netlify.com/)). However, when deployment is complete, the site looks different than it does locally. For example, my grid layout does not work properly.

I can see that the styles are being packaged differently than they are locally. Netlify is creating some `/static/css/*.chunk.css` files which does indeed contain my styles. When deployed locally, the styles are simply added in the `<head>` tag of the parent document as `<style type="text/css">`

I have tried turning off asset optimization in Netlify. I have also tried renaming my CSS classes, and even included it directly on the index.js file of the create-react-app project. Nothing seems to make a difference.

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "knowledge-repo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@toast-ui/react-editor": "^1.0.0",
    "array-move": "^2.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.13",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-ace": "^6.5.0",
    "react-codemirror": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.9.1",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.4.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.86.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "run-p start:**",
    "start:app": "react-scripts start",
    "start:lambda": "netlify-lambda serve src/lambda",
    "build": "run-p build:**",
    "build:app": "react-scripts build",
    "build:lambda": "netlify-lambda build src/lambda",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "netlify-lambda": "^1.4.13",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Here is the component that is using the `*.css`

```js
import React from 'react';
import KnowledgeSubjectBrowser from './KnowledgeSubjectBrowser';
import KnowledgeRepoHeader from './KnowledgeRepoHeader';
import KnowledgeRepoSidebar from './KnowledgeRepoSidebar';
import styles from './KnowledgeRepo.css'

class KnowledgeRepo extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return (
      <div className={styles.krcontainer}>
        <header>
          <KnowledgeRepoHeader />
        </header>
        <nav>
          <KnowledgeRepoSidebar />
        </nav>
        <main>
          <KnowledgeSubjectBrowser />
        </main>
      </div>
        )
    }
}

export default KnowledgeRepo;
```

The css file as follows:

```css
:local(.krcontainer) {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "nav content side";

  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 200px;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0px;

  height: 100vh;

}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: black;
}

nav {
  padding: 30px 5px 20px 5px;
  grid-area: nav;
  background: black;
}

main {
  grid-area: content;
}
```

Comment: The className should be `"krcontainer"` not `{styles.krcontainer}`. In a CSS file you set styles for classnames, ids etc. but you do not have an object type with keys that you can use like you did (`styles.krcontainer`). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. There was a semi-colon at the very end of my css file (typo). Netlify bundles all static files together and therefore the bundled css artifact was not loading properly.

Comment: Thanks! This saved a ton of time

Comment: was the semicolon typo not included in the original post? i dont see any typo there

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. For me, it was because I had an empty file import.

In my `main.css` file, I had the following imports:

```
@import url("./reset.css");
@import url("./core-styles.css");
@import url("./buttons.css");
```

However, I deleted the `reset.css` stylesheet file (while keeping it in the imports) in favor of a different strategy. Everything still built but was not bundling correctly and a few styles were not being handled correctly by Netlify on the deployed site.

Once I removed it from my `main.css` file (as there was no actual file) everything worked again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. what worked for me is removing the [PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/guides/react.html) postbuild script in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "postbuild": "purgecss --css build/static/css/*.css --content build/index.html build/static/js/*.js --output build/static/css"
 },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).